# How to anticipate whether a multivariate model will perform better than separate univariate models?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, cross-correlation, granger-causality

As the title says, I would like to know if there are any statistics or methods to check if a group of time series is *multiple* (i.e., independent) or *multivariate* (i.e., in the sense that they show some grade of correlation between them), so I can better choose which time series analysis models are most appropriate to study such group of time series (for example, individual ARIMA models vs vector  ARIMA).
I guess one could apply some causality test, like that of Granger, to infer causality between the individual time series, but since I have not seen any paper regarding this specific question I'm a bit lost.

Thank you in advance!

---

### Edit

To make the specific problem -from which the above discussion stems- (hopefully) clearer, when trying to forecast a group of time series, **can we check *beforehand* whether a multivariate model will perform better than separate univariate models**? If so, how?

Comment: The way use use the terms *multiple* and *multivariate* is nonstandard. It would make more sense to ask how to check whether a group of time series are independent or uncorrelated (whichever you are interested in).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I didn't know this was nonstandard nomenclature. The way I was refering to those terms was as in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365394/254006).
Nevertheless, I'll reformat my question to make it clearer then.

Comment: I have edited the title to better reflect the issue. If you feel it is not an improvement, feel free to reverse to the original title. (For me the original one was really not helpful.) Regarding the linked post, I see some sense there but only some, and in my view it does not carry over to this post.

Comment: @RichardHardy I totally agree with the edited title, thanks.

Comment: The answer depends on which models you are comparing.  Can you tell us more about what you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber Initially, I was thinking about ARIMA and its vectorial version VARIMA.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "check beforehand"?  Before what event?  Using what information?

Comment: Sure thanks! I was referring to check it withouth doing it the straight way, that is, fitting the models and checking the goodness of the forecast for each of them.

Comment: As a general proposition, this question is unanswerable, because it will depend on the models you have in mind and on how you measure performance.